# Calling ExecutorService.shutdown in a dynamic thread number

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

Good Morning in my timezone.

I am using thread pool to develop a little Http robot that travels from link to link in each page.When i found  a new link i create a new thread that will explore that new page.
Pseudo code.

```
pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(40);

pool.execute(new Exploit(tree.getRoot()));
```

In this case the Exploit is a inner class that implements Runnable interface and have access to pool, so each time one thread finds a link, will use the pool to add a new "thread" like this way:

```
for(Link n : links){
   pool.execute(new Exploit(n));
 }
```

I saw a lot of examples using ExecutorService class but all of them use the same sort of code like this :

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(10000000L + i);
    executor.execute(worker);
}
   // This will make the executor accept no new threads
   // and finish all existing threads in the queue
    executor.shutdown();
```

In the above code , the number the threads is static so when the code calls shutdown all the threads had already been added to the pool.I can not follow this code because in my case i do not have a static number of threads to add. My stop condition to add more threads to the pool is when i reached a searching deep level.So my question is , how do i call executor.shutdown in the main thread ? Is there any kind of join that i can use in the main thread ?

Thanks in advance.
Best Regards

Comment: let me understand: your system recursively scans for links in a page and creates a scan task for every link found. This task is scheduled in an executor and you would like to shutdown the executor when there are no more tasks to be executed. Two questions: (1) How does a task know when to stop? i.e. If I'm in level n, do I know that I should/or not scan level n+1?  How are you avoiding link loops?

Comment: My stop condition is related with level achievement.
When the new task see that the parent have one specific level, lets say 3 then this new task will have 4 and if the stop condition is marked as 3 then will stop immediatelly and do not has more task to the pool.

Comment: did you finally solve this question with the info you had so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html).  You can still use a fixed number of threads, but each time you find a link you can register another party and submit a runnable based on that link.

```
Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);
ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);

public void crawl(final String url){
   visit(url);
   phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
   e.shutdown();  
}

private void visit(String url){
    phaser.register();
    e.submit(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            //visit link maybe another visit(url)             
            phaser.arrive();
        } 
    });
}
```

At this point e.shutdown() will never occur until all links have been visited.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of how many tasks are currently in the pool.  Increment a counter before every call to execute().  Then decrement the counter at the end of every task, make sure you do this even when there is an exception.

Then the code that will shutdown the executor (one posting the first task), should wait in a while loop to see if the counter is 0.

The decrementing code should use notify to wake the main thread up.

```
class TaskCounter {
   private final Object lock = new Object();
   private long count;

   public void taskStart() {
      synchronize (lock) {
         count++;
      }
   }

   public void taskEnd() {
      synchronize (lock) {
         count--;
         if (count == 0) {
            lock.notify();
         }
      }
   }

   public void waitForAllTasksToComplete() throws InterruptedException {
      synchronize (lock) {
         while (count != 0) {
            lock.wait();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer :).
I develop one very similar solution using indexes(AtomicInteger), the pool itself is the monitor lock that i am using

Answer (score 0):

In the code you show, you *do* have a static number of threads. `newFixedThreadPool` creates a thread pool with a fixed number of threads.

When you call `pool.execute`, you don't create a new thread. You create a new task, which will be executed by one of the existing threads. That's the whole point of a thread pool.

Comment: Better explained than in my answer !!

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer , but i did not correctly explain what is my problem.I know i have a static number of threads, what i do not have is a static number of task, each task could add more taks to the pool, in the other examples what they show me is a static number of tasks to.So with a dynamic numeber of task how can i call shutdown in the main task ?

Comment: Just call `shutdown()`. Any tasks already created will be executed, no matter how many of them there are, then the threads will all stop.

Comment: Or is your problem not *how* to shut down, but *when*? Is it that you don't know when it's the right time to call `shutdown()`?

Comment: But the problem is if i "just" call shutdown , some of the active task could add more tasks to the pool, and in that time it throws an exception that indicates that i can not add more tasks to the pool.I have to have a way to know that there is not any active tasks inside the pool to call shutdown

Comment: Yes my problem is when to shutdown, i think this is the typicall "Crawler" problem, i like navigating a tree, i do not know in the beggining how many task we would have because we add task dynamically to the pool, i have to find a way to know when there is not any active tasks in the pool

Comment: Take a look at the [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html)

Comment: I develop a solution that works well:
I have an index that is atomic (AtomicInteger) that stores the number of active tasks, each task increments this index in the constructor and decrements it in the end of the run.In the main thread i called the wait method over the pool.In each tasks , in the end of the run method i test if there are any active task, if there are not i call notify in the pool object.Just after the wait method wakes up i then call shutdown in the pool

Answer (score 0):

`newFixedThreadPool` will only set number of threads executed at the same time.  It does not specify the number of threads you can put in the executor service.  So you can add as many threads as you want in your main thread, launch `execute()` and `shutdown()` the ExecutorService when you consider you'll add no more